# hadoop + how to rebalnce the hdfs

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, hdp

we have HDP cluster version `2.6.5` with `8` data nodes  , all machines are installed on rhel 7.6 version

HDP cluster is based amabri platform version - `2.6.1`

each data-node ( worker machine ) include two disks and each disk size is 1.8T

when we access the data-node machines we can see differences between the size of the disks

for example on the first data-node the size is : ( by `df -h` )

```
/dev/sdb                  1.8T  839G  996G  46% /grid/sdc
/dev/sda                  1.8T 1014G  821G  56% /grid/sdb
```

on the second data-node the size is:

```
/dev/sdb                  1.8T  1.5T  390G  79% /grid/sdc
/dev/sda                  1.8T  1.5T  400G  79% /grid/sdb
```

on the third data-node th size is:

```
/dev/sdb                  1.8T  1.7T  170G  91% /grid/sdc
/dev/sda                  1.8T  1.7T  169G  91% /grid/sdb
```

and so on

the big question is why HDFS not perform the re-balance on the HDFS disks?

*for example expected results on all disks should be with the same size on all datanodes machines*

why is the used size differences between `datanode1` to `datanode2` to `datanode3` etc ?

any advice about the tune parameters in HDFS that can help us?

*because its very critical when one disk is reached `100%` size and the other are more small as `50%`*

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is known behaviour of the hdfs re-balancer in **HDP 2.6**, There are many reasons for unbalanced block distribution. [Click](https://docs.cloudera.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.6.3/bk_hdfs-administration/content/hdfs_data_unbalanced.html) to check all the possible reasons.

With [HDFS-1312](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HDFS-1312) a disk balance option have been introduced to address this issue.

Following articles shall help you tune it more efficiently:-

1. [HDFS Balancer (1): 100x Performance Improvement](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Community-Articles/HDFS-Balancer-1-100x-Performance-Improvement/ta-p/246648)
2. [HDFS Balancer (2): Configurations & CLI Options](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Community-Articles/HDFS-Balancer-2-Configurations-CLI-Options/ta-p/246687)
3. [HDFS Balancer (3): Cluster Balancing Algorithm](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Community-Articles/HDFS-Balancer-3-Cluster-Balancing-Algorithm/ta-p/246733)

I would suggest to upgrade to HDP3.X as HDP 2.x is [not supported](https://www.cloudera.com/legal/policies/support-lifecycle-policy.html) anymore by Cloudera Support.

Comment: I see  that https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HDFS-1312 is only for HDP 3.X , so how we can use it?

Comment: regarding to https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HDFS-1312 , not clear which packages need to install or which tune settings need to configure in HDFS config in ambari

Comment: I would not suggest to use it if its not there, it was a major upgrade for hdfs and there are high chances we might break something.

Comment: You can try setting **dfs.datanode.du.reserved** to something like 10GB, it will apply to every volume on the datanodes used by hdfs and will not use the 10GB for non-hdfs use. For hdp 2.6 this is the best way for now.

Comment: as you can see each disk is 1.8T , so if I set 10G for dfs.datanode.du.reserved , then how it can help to re balance the disks to be the same used size?

Comment: I also checked this dfs.datanode.du.reserved and its already set to 10G

Comment: so do you recommended to increase the dfs.datanode.du.reserved?

Comment: if its set to 10GB then leave it like that for now. 10 G should be enough